# Algorithm for max integer in an array of integers

Tags: algorithm, mergesort, bubble-sort

If we need to implement a function that takes an array of integers and returns the maximum integer in the collection, assuming that the length of the array is less than 1000. Would you use Bubble Sort or Merge Sort and Why?

Also, what happens to the above algorithm choice, if the array length is greater than 1000? I am a bit confused on why I should use a particular algorithm over another one. Is it just due to its complexity and time or other factors also involved in this? What if I have to test out the above function and that takes a lot more time for a simple algorithm and less time for a complex one?

Comment: This sounds rather like homework. Could you please flag it as such if that's the case?

Comment: if the array length is greater than 1000, well, the bubbles will go off.

Comment: This doesn't deserve two downvotes just because it smells like homework.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I wouldn't sort at all. I'd just traverse the array and keep track of the largest one as I go. This takes O(N) time, whereas a sort algorithms generally won't do better than O(N*log(N)).

Comment: +1: OP's intention to sort is bizarre for this.  I wonder if there is another underlying requirement.

Comment: Also sorting can get worse than O(N * logN) if you choose a bad algorithm

Answer (score 3):

This site rocks

http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Comment: +1, not directly related to the question though :P but good site.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you MUST sort, then use merge sort because it's a lot faster than bubble sort. For 1000 elements and a single sort you probably won't notice the difference on a modern computer, but for more elements (I'm thinking >= 10 000) the difference becomes notieceable.

Answer (score 0):

Lets call the length of your array N.

Sorting the array using Bubble Sort takes roughly in the order of N*N units of time.

Sorting it using Merge Sort takes in the order of N * log N units of time.

Simply looking at each element one after one and keeping track of which one is the biggest will take in the order of N units of time.

Hence, use the last method.